# Why adding a certificate to cacerts is not enough?

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, networking, https

I have a Java program that connects to an https remote webservice which exposes a TLS certificate of this structure:

```
Webservice certificate
    Signed with some certificate
        Signed with some corporate certificate
```

Now, when my Java app makes a https request to that webservice it fails due to invalid certificate. This is normal, so I added the webservice direct certificate to the Java/lib/security/cacerts file.

But this didn't work, I still had the certificate exception.

After a long debugging session and hours wasted, I tried to add all three individual certificates, and this time it worked. But why ?

Why does Java checks the full certificate path **even though the direct certificate is made trusted** ?

**Is this behavior as per SSL/TLS RFCs** ? Will this behavior occur with other tools/languages like `curl` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... so I added the webservice direct certificate to the Java/lib/security/cacerts file

The webservice certificate is not a CA certificate, so it does not belong in cacerts in the first place (as the name indicates). A CA certificate is a certificate which is used to sign other certificates, a webservice certificate is a leaf certificate which cannot be used to sign other certificates.

> Will this behavior occur with other tools/languages like curl ?

This is a common behavior. With OpenSSL based tools one usually needs to provide the root CA (and of course the chain to it), only with X509_V_FLAG_PARTIAL_CHAIN it will accept when parts of the chain a specified as trusted.

Comment: Makes sense that the keystore name is `cacerts`. Great. Do you know a way in java to trust only a leaf certificate?

Comment: @Mike: *"trust only a leaf certificate?"* - this is basically certificate pinning or public key pinning. You don't base trust on a CA but expect exactly a specific certificate, no matter who the issuer is, if revoked, if expired ... . Usually not a good idea since it does not scale well if the server renews the certificate. But might make sense for self-signed certificates. Basic idea is to disable normal certificate validation, extract the certificate/key and check it (or its fingerprint) against your specific expectation.

Comment: DANE is exactly about providing support, through DNS records, to signal validity of specific CA/end certificate/public key or hash of it. It needs obviously specific support on the client side, but depending on how it is used it allows to completed bypass the broken WebPKI model. Unfortunately browsers do not support it. Some HTTP client libraries may however and if you develop your own protocol over TLS there is no constraint not to support this use case.